# How to add a bar on top of a UISplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, subclassing

I would like to have a separate bar above the UISplitViewController on iPad. I will use this bar to show a logo.
I did some googling and reading but cannot find a solution to this other than create my completely own subclass to draw my screen like I want it. I'd like to avoid that if possible...

Comment: Not navigation bars on the master and detail, a navigation bar above both?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about ViewController Containment to build your own Container Controller.

Helpful links:

- `iOS Reference:` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- `objc.io article:`
  http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html

Answer (score 0):

Create your own container view controller. In its view this VC will add a navigation bar (or some other view that you can add your logo to) and the split view controllers view. It should also add the split VC as a child.

This is a custom subclass that you will create, but it is minimal code and requires no `drawing` code from you.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising! Thanks, I'll look into it.